# Animating the width of a fixed element

Tags: css

Im having troubles animating the width of a fixed element on page load.

Here is my CSS :

```
.background-right {
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  left:50%;
  z-index:-1;
  background:#e4d7ca;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.background-right.hidden {
  position:fixed;
  width:0%;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  left:50%;
  z-index:-1;
  background:#e4d7ca;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Any ideas why its not working ?

Its to be used in a WordPress theme and the html for it is simply :

```
<div class="background-left"></div>
<div class="background-right hidden"></div>
```

and on page load the hidden class is removed using jquery.

Thanks,

Scott.

Comment: of course. I have updated the post.

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: it doesnt animate, it just jumps straight to 100% width.

Comment: Seems to work for me: https://jsfiddle.net/f5hspm3a/

Comment: Thats strange, not sure why it isnt working on my theme

Comment: Found the problem. I had a class called hidden which had display set to none. doh.